# create log file using typescript in node application

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am new in node and I need to have a **log file which stores error log details**
I need guidance to make log file generated using typescript (node)

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_writestream

Comment: You can also take  look at [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)

Comment: dear @SelloMkantjwa would give me some link where I can refer to typescript version fo Winston because I google it but all are in js example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi use [log4js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js) module,

```
var log4js = require('log4js'); //include
var errorLog = {
  module: "module name",
  location: "location name",
  line: "72",
  message: err //error object
};
log4js.getLogger().error(errorLog); //writing log file
```

go through with the log4js documentation for more details about configuration

Comment: log4js is also available for typescript? because my node  is on typescript

Comment: you can use log4ts instead if you are fully using typescript.